# HighCharts Orgcharts make scroll able container

Tags: javascript, highcharts, orgchart

I had a problem with highcharts organization chart. The problem is, that chart will be a big one, and I need horizontal scrollbar for container of chart, or make chart horizontally scrollable.

I have tried to enable scrollbar of chart or make container of chart scrollable using css, but no luck, highcharts trying to fit chart within window size, which is unacceptable for this case.

Tried enable scrollbar by using js code below

```
scrollbar: {
    enabled:true,
    barBackgroundColor: 'gray',
    barBorderRadius: 7,
    barBorderWidth: 0,
    buttonBackgroundColor: 'gray',
    buttonBorderWidth: 0,
    buttonArrowColor: 'yellow',
    buttonBorderRadius: 7,
    rifleColor: 'yellow',
    trackBackgroundColor: 'white',
    trackBorderWidth: 1,
    trackBorderColor: 'silver',
    trackBorderRadius: 7
},
```

and with css using style for container like

```
<style>
#container {
    min-width: 300px;
    margin: 1em auto;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    overflow: scroll !important;
}

#container h4 {
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#container p {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 16px;
}
</style>
```

Results can be viewed in fiddle provided below

https://jsfiddle.net/72v36msx/

So the question is - are there any way to make chart horizontally scrollable and get nice view, without making nodes so small, as it is in the fiddle, that I provided.

Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

The `scrollbar` feature is available only for Highstock. To create a custom scrollbar set `chart.width` to a higher value than container width.

CSS:

```
#container {
    min-width: 300px;
    overflow: scroll !important;
}
```

JS:

```
chart: {
    width: 1200,
    ...
}
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5hpk3e9d/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.width